# Field value displaying it's default value instead of null even though field is null in the database

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, voyager

Why is the avatar field returning the default value rather than null which is what it actually is in the database???

***Result***

[image]

***Query***

```
$f1 = User::where('id','=',3194)->first();
dd($f1->avatar);
```

***Database***
[image]

Comment: Please show view page code and query output to understand problem.

Comment: what is result of `dd($f1)`. You don't need to use `=` in where statement btw.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `User` model here aswell?